# R script, ggplot2 and qplot, multiple time series line plots on the same graph

Tags: r

I want to have multiple "lines" on the same plot.   Multiple data points.

In my example, how can I include the 'xa' and 'xb' data points.

This is what I have for just one set of data points but I want two.  How can I modify this script.

```
library(ggplot2)

da <- c("2012-02-02 09:01:00", "2012-02-02 09:02:00", "2012-02-02 09:03:00")
db <- c(0.4, 0.6, 0.5)

xa <- c("2012-02-02 09:01:00", "2012-02-02 09:02:00", "2012-02-02 09:03:00")
xb <- c(0.3, 0.43, 0.7)

da2 <- as.POSIXct(da)
dfx <- data.frame(da2, db)

summary(dfx)

png('time_data_errs6b.png', width=640, height=480)
gg <- qplot(da2, db, colour='red')+
    opts(title = 'Requests App')+xlab('Time')+ylab('Requests') +
    geom_line()

print(gg)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Observation: the `gg <- qplot(...)` statement now (June 2015; R version 3.1.1) generates `Error: Use 'theme' instead. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.1)`.  The error refers to the use of `opts(title='Requests App')`.  It appears that the direct replacement for `opts` (in this context) is `labs(title='Requests App')`, optionally modified by a theme such as `theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2), colour = "blue"))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make two `data.frames` and `merge` them  by the time variable.

```
> df.a<-data.frame(time=da, value.a=db)
> df.b<-data.frame(time=xa, value.b=xb)
> df.mix<-merge(df.a, df.b, by='time')

> df.mix
                 time value.a value.b
1 2012-02-02 09:01:00     0.4    0.30
2 2012-02-02 09:02:00     0.6    0.43
3 2012-02-02 09:03:00     0.5    0.70
```

Convert to POSIXct like you did then melt it to a long format.

```
> df.mix$time<-as.POSIXct(df.mix$time)
> df.melt<-melt(df.mix, id.vars='time')
```

ggplot deals with long format data very well, so its usually my goal to get data into a suitable structure with `melt` and `merge` before plotting.

```
> ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=time, y=value, colour=variable)) + geom_path()
```

I also like to uses the base `ggplot` rather than `qplot` for my own readability.  but thats a matter of preference.

Comment: This was very helpful. One question: can you explain your comment on using ggplot rather than qplot?

Comment: When I build a complex plot, I like the syntax of using `ggplot` to establish the variables common to all geoms and the individual geom to   assign their specifics.  `ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value)) + geom_line(aes(color=some_category)) + geom_point(aes(size=some_other_category))`  does that help?  if not, feel free to ask a question of your own and I'll chime in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much simpler approach, without the need to `merge` or `melt` data.

```
df_a <- data.frame(time = da, value = db)
df_b <- data.frame(time = xa, value = xb)
ggplot(df_a, aes(x = as.POSIXct(time), y = value)) +
  geom_line(col = 'red') + 
  geom_line(col = 'blue', data = df_b)
```

Comment: I find this approach more complex.  It requires two separate geoms and  makes it significantly more complicated if you need a legend or need more than two coloring variables.

Comment: for the question in the post, i think it is a really round-about solution to `merge` then `melt` data, when you could do with a fewer operations and lines of code. for a more generic problem, yes the efficiency gains might pay off.

Comment: Either way.  Can I simply add another geom_line if I need to add another line/set of points.